# Appcelerator Hyperloop Android handle return data

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, hyperloop

I am trying to use Hyperloop to wrap the Estimote SDK. I've made some significant progress and have been able to range for and find beacons.

My problem is with the data returned from the Estimote SDK. The onBeaconsDiscovered event returns all the beacons found in a List (java.util.List) and I can't seem to do anything with it. Trying to call a method on the list results in 'not a function errors' ie: beaconsRanged.size() gives me beaconsRanged.size is not a function.

I also tried to print the object to the console, but that gave me 'maximum call stack exceeded' errors.

What is the proper way to handle this type of return data?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an open ticket about Lists in Hyperloop: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24684

That might block this from working